# How to unbind Ctrl+LeftClick in tmux?

Tags: tmux, kitty

KiTTY (the [Windows-based PuTTY clone](https://kitty.9bis.net), not the [other terminal emulator](https://sw.kovidgoyal.net/kitty/)) has an option that underscores URLs in terminal output and, when Ctrl+LeftClick'd, opens them in the host browser.

This works outside of tmux. It also works inside of a tmux session with `set-option -g mouse off`. It *doesn't* work with `set-option -g mouse on`, which makes me think that what's happening is `tmux` intercepting the Ctrl+LeftClick.

I tried unbinding left-click on pane in `tmux.conf`, but that didn't help:

```
unbind MouseDown1Pane
unbind C-MouseDown1Pane
unbind M-MouseDown1Pane
```

Is there a way to stop tmux from intercepting just the Ctrl+LeftClick while preserving the rest of its mouse functionality?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. There is no way for tmux to tell the outside terminal it only wants some mouse events, it is all or nothing.

You can configure what tmux does for different mouse events by changing the key bindings, but there is no way to have the outside terminal handle them instead without turning off the mouse in tmux entirely.

However, most terminals provide a way to bypass the application - in xterm you press Shift when using the mouse, perhaps Kitty has a way too.

Comment: [It is configurable in PuTTY](https://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.73/htmldoc/Chapter4.html#config-mouseshift).  KiTTY does not appear to have a single user manual like that.  It _might_ be configurable in KiTTY.

Comment: Shift-LeftClick does bypass tmux for text selection + copying; Ctrl-Shift-LeftClick, apparently, doesn't. Luckily, there's a Kitty setting that allows plain LeftClick on hyperlink to launch it, which means Shift-LeftClick works.